# How to set Sum of Two Columns in update query

Tags: mysql

**

> How to set Sum of Two Columns in update query

**

```
INSERT INTO account (id, cid, stock, stockAvailable, sumStock) VALUES (1, '1','10', '20', '0'), (2,'1', '10', '20', '0');

    UPDATE account SET sumStock=SUM(stock)  FROM account where cid= '1'
```

Comment: How to set Sum Of one column in Sum Function

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this is by referring to the same table with different aliases and joining them:

`UPDATE account AS a1
 INNER JOIN (
   SELECT SUM(stock) AS count FROM account 
 ) AS a2 ON a1.cid = a2.cid
 SET a1.sumStock=a2.count WHERE a1.cid= '1'`

Comment: UPDATE account SET sumStock = (select v1.stock1 from (Select SUM(stock) as stock1 from account WHERE did ='1') as v1 ) WHERE id = '1'